# How to select multiple nodes in SSAS hierarchical dimension?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssas

I'm working on a SSAS project in order to load information in PowerPivot.

I need to create something easy to use : allow user to select multiple nodes in a hierarchy.
For example to get all sales for "Europe" sub entities and "Pacific" sub entities.

Here is a sample of a dimension.

[image]

So, is there a way to be able to select multiple nodes : for example "Europe" and "Pacific".
In fact the SSAS import wizard only allow to pick one node.

If I display the attribute dimension I can filter leaf by leaf, but it's not relevant, a node can own more than 50 sub elements, and it's tricky to select all of them.

Any idea to do that ?

PS : my dimension is based on a parent/child relationship (self referenced by a parent_id field).

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you trying to import data from SSAS into Power Pivot? Is this a one-time set up thing, or something business users might need to do repeatedly? You can write MDX to get Europe, Pacific, and all their descendants, but you can't expect business users to know MDX. Also, are you sure you need both the SSAS project and Power Pivot? Typically, you use one or the other, and only import data from SSAS to Power Pivot if you need to integrate the SSAS data with data from another source that can't be added to the the SSAS database.

Comment: Yes I load SSAS data source in PowerPivot to build self service reports trough Power View. As you said business users don't know MDX and it's why I would like to be able to select multiple nodes. Today I use DECENDANTS() and UNION() in my filter as MDX query.

Comment: Are you using Excel 2013? If so, is the use of Power Query a possibility? It has support for SSAS and hierarchies http://blogs.office.com/2014/11/25/power-query-november-2014-update-connect-analysis-services-salesforce/

Comment: Yes, it's Excel 2013 but I don't have to use PowerQuery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, it seems it's not possible to select some nodes including elements by using SSAS Import Wizard (drag & drop).

To solve my issue, i added a filter on my parent/child hierarchy and I selected a MDX query to add the following script :

```
UNION(DESCENDANTS([Dimension].[Hierarchy].[&<node1>]), DESCENDANTS([Dimension].[Hierarchy].[&<node2>]))
```

and  are the IDs of my nodes.